# php date doesn't calculate in the right way

Tags: php, date

I want to calculate the difference between two timestamp and then convert them back to into readable human date, but I'm getting extra 2 hours added to my date ! I don't know why.

```
$data = $row['date_future']; // 1363473942
$time = time(); // 1363472242

//echoing future date
echo "Future time: ".date('H:i:s', $data)."<br/>";
echo "Current time:".date('H:i:s', $time)."<br/>";
```

**OUTPUT:**

> Future time: 00:45:42
>
> Current time: 00:17:22

It's okay, but when I'm trying to calculate the difference I'm getting extra 2 hours !

```
echo "Difference: ".date('H:i:s', $data-$time);
```

OUTPUT:

> Difference: 02:28:20

**FIX:**

```
$d1 = new DateTime(date('H:i:s', $data));
$d2 = new DateTime(date('H:i:s', $time));
$interval = date_diff($d2, $d1);

echo "Difference: ".($interval->format('%H:%i:%s'))
```

**OUTPUT:**

> Difference: 00:28:20

Comment: Try `echo "Difference: ".date('H:i:s', $data-$time+86400);` and post results - this is a test if my theory is correct.

Comment: I'm getting the right result: http://codepad.org/TNwDTxCw. I'm guessing you're having a timezone issue. Try to use the [`DateTime::diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method instead.

Comment: This looks like daylight saving time issues. WHich timezone are you in?

Comment: @EugenRieck I'm getting the same result: Difference: 02:28:20

Comment: `date('H:i:s', $data-$time);` yields a couple of minutes or hours after the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00) +- a dozen or so hours depending on your current timezone relative to GMT.  You probably don't want to be adding/subtracting dates using this method.

Comment: @ZbarceaChristian So if you have GTU +2 you get a 2 hours difference :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really a timezone issue (at least not one of *setting* the right timezone parameter in the PHP config) – it’s a matter of flawed logic.

Unix timestamps are given in seconds from 1.1.1970, 00:00:00 UTC.

1363473942 - 1363472242 is 1700 – and when you look not only at the H:i:s part of that date, it should become obvious:

```
echo "Difference: ".date('r', $data-$time); // replaced format H:i:s with r
```

This outputs

> Difference: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:28:20 +0100

– so we are looking at a completely different *date* here, and with timezone offsets and DST on/off at the different points in time differences that may not seem logical at first glance are in reality to be expected.

Subtracting to unix timestamps from another results in a number of seconds – but it is not a unix timestamp that would have *any* relation to the original timestamps any more.

Formatting this difference assuming it was a meaningful unix timestamp is therefor bound to fail.

Using for example [DateTime::diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) would be a *sensible* approach to handle this.

Answer (score 3):

The timestamps are unix timestamps and they represent the amount of time (in seconds) passed since midnight UTC, 1 January 1970.

The difference between the two timestamps is 1700 seconds, so it represents the date 1700 seconds after midnight UTC on 1 January 1970 which is 1 January 1970, 0:28 UTC. You must be 2 hours ahead of UTC so it is shown as 1 January, 2:28.